# Tweeter Premium API- cannot set up a Dev environment

Tags: python, api, twitter, extract, tweepy

I am trying to get tweets from twitter using the free version of Premium API. The problem is that I cannot set up a Dev environment because I cannot find anything clickable in the Dev environments. Look at the image below. Does anyone have any idea?
[image]

Comment: Have you been through the process of applying for a Developer Account, or did you already have older apps in the portal and not have an approved account? There should be a "Set up dev environment" button on the right hand side of the screen under each option, if you have an approved account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I applied for a Developer account, created an app, and test my script with the Standard ApI. Now I want to run my script using the Premium API, but I can't set it up. I am not sure what's missing here that the "Set up dev environment" button does not show up.

Comment: Have you tried an alternative browser? Maybe it is something in the browser hiding the button. Just an idea.